# FileWatcher not triggering event when a folder is added

Tags: c#, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

I'm using [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to get events when a folder content changes. I have managed to successfully watch for events when a file is added, deleted or renamed, but the event is not being triggered when a new folder is created within the directory that I'm watching.

I have tried with the following events:

```
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.Attributes;
```

I have also set the following two properties to be `true`, though it did not help

```
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
```

Is this possible to do with `FileSystemWatcher` or do I need to use something else?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `NotifyFilters.DirectoryName`?

Comment: May it be that you used `watch.Filter` anywhere in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't include Directories

```
NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
```

In your notifyfilter.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters(v=vs.110).aspx

so you should setup your notifyfilter as follows:

```
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
                       NotifyFilters.LastAccess | 
                       NotifyFilters.LastWrite | 
                       NotifyFilters.FileName | 
                       NotifyFilters.Size | 
                       NotifyFilters.Attributes;
```

I didn't verify and you didn't mention it but having  [`Filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) set might filter out a diectory, although the docs speaks about *Gets or sets the filter string used to determine what files are monitored in a directory.*

Comment: I believe the enum elements: `NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite |  NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.Attributes` work for folders or files whether or not you use `NotifyFilters.DirectoryName`

Comment: @AshwinNair This is not true. You have to include `NotifyFilters.DirectoryName`

Comment: @rene It is worth including that a specific filter like `"*.txt"` ruins this setup. It needs to be either not set, or set to anything (`"*.*"`)

Comment: @user3185569 added that, will test later.

Comment: I was assuming that the `DirectoryName` was watching only the changes to the name of the directory in `Path`. Thanks!